# Как обратиться к переменной из другой функции?

Tags: python

хочу найти способ обратиться к одной переменной из другой функции, без объявления ее глобальной переменной, можно ли так сделать? Код для примера:

```
def num1():
  num_1 = 23

def num2():
  num_2 = num_1 * 2
  print(num_2)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    num1()
    num2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Делайте правильно - передавайте все параметры явно в функцию (если функция должна что-то получить) и получайте результат работы функции через `return` (если функция должна что-то вернуть). Такие функции просто тестировать - у них нет "побочных эффектов", которые сложно отслеживать и сложно тестировать:

```
def num1():
  return 23

def num2(num_1):
  num_2 = num_1 * 2
  print(num_2)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    num_1 = num1()
    num2(num_1)
```